# Ember.js access model values

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to be able to modify/validate data before actually saving.

#### Model

```
  App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('date', { defaultValue: new Date() }),  
  excerpt: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
  });
```

#### Route

```
App.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').createRecord('post');
  },
  actions: {
    doneEditing: function() {      
      debugger;          
      this.modelFor('postsNew').save();
      this.transitionTo('posts.index');
    }
  }
});
```

So, the questions, before the `.save()` I want to, let's say, validate that the title is not empty or so.

1. Everything I've tried gets undefined, or [Object object] has no .val() method. I don't know how to get to the values of the model. How can I do that?
2. And the other thing I have in mind. Is that defaultValue working as intended? I want to set Date() to every new created post. Somehow `date` is not being recorded since it's not showing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
App.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').createRecord('post');
  },
  actions: {
    doneEditing: function() {      
      debugger;          
      var model = this.modelFor('postsNew');
      var title =  model.get('title');
      model.save();
      this.transitionTo('posts.index');
    }
  }
});
```